# React + Express Cannot get /login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I know there is a bunch of questions about this but none of them fixed my issue.
I have a react client app with react router `<Route path="/login" component={Login} />` and when the user fails to login in my express i have `

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))
```

so the user stays on /login but when the page is refreshed i got the error `Cannot GET /login`.
Made a lot of researches in the net and some of them says to create a wildcard route like this:

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
 app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/index.html'));
 }); // this is below all other routes
```

Added in webpack.config.dev.js the following code:

```
devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true
}
```

But after that i got `Unexpected token < in 1.fce49d06.chunk.js:1` in the browser console. After that read about `babel-register` to transpile my node code so I created a new file `start.js` like this:

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'env', 'es2015', 'react' ]
})
require("babel-polyfill")

module.exports = require('./index.js');
```

Also in the server's package.json i have

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node start.js",
   "server": "nodemon start.js",
   "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
   "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
```

But still there is Unexpected token < 
Any Ideas?

Comment: So, the problem is basically when the page is refreshed? does this happen with all your routes (refresh and then the get error) or is it only in the login redirection?

Comment: Only with /login for now, because only it has node redirect `failureRedirect: '/login',` my other routes are only in react-router for now

Comment: Does your router in the front end handle the `/login` route?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem comes from that wildcard route which sends index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use **connect-history-api-fallback** middleware

You can use the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware to always fallback to index.html. This can be used in both dev and prod environments.

Use it like this:

```
const connectHistoryApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

... // require other libraries...
... // app.use( other middleware ...

app.use(connectHistoryApiFallback({
  verbose: false
}));

// static files and folders must be set after connectHistoryApiFallback
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

... // other routes 

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}))

// app.listen...
```

Comment: Does it mean to remove the wildcard route?

Comment: with this middleware you don't need the wildcard route. If your index.html is not found, try to set its location using [this property](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#index) from the docs.

Comment: not working...again the same Unexpected token < . If I remove this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));` then Unexpected token error is gone but Cannot get /login is logged

Comment: Try this solution without the change in `webpack.config.dev.js` or the `babel-register`... the `<` problem is a different one.

Comment: yep, I removed
 `devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true
}` and got rid of babel so now my main server file is index.js not start.js(the one with babel) and still Unexpected token <

Comment: can you add your webpack config to the question?

Comment: Its the default webpack config that create-react-app creates only added sass module to write scss. I was wondering why on `successRedirect: '/'` it is working but redirect to /login not